# When is the solution to a Fredholm integral equation a PDF?

Tags: st.statistics, integral-operators, fredholm-operators

I have two questions about inhomogenous Fredholm integral equations of the first kind:
$$f(x) = \int_a^b K(x,t) g(t) dt$$
where $f, K$ are known and $g$ is not.

1. If a unique solution for $g$ exists, under what conditions is $g$ a probability density function -- i.e., a positive function that integrates to 1?
2. For the regression equation
   $$r(x) \equiv E[Y | X=x] = \int_a^b E[Y | X=x, Z=z; \beta] g(z) dz,$$
   solved by $g$ and $\beta$, must there exist another solution with $g’\neq g$ and $\beta’\neq\beta$? The regression function integrates over $Z$, which is not observed. I am particularly interested in cases of the form $$r(x) =\int_a^b \exp(-\exp(z + \beta x))\,g(z)dz$$ and using this to show that the parameter $\beta$ is not statistically identified.

Comment: @MattF. sure, I've now done so

Comment: @MattF. -- to clarify, I'm interested in the case where there exists a $\beta, g$ that solves $r(x) = \int_a^b exp(-exp(z+\beta x)) g(z) dz$, but am not sure whether that $\beta, g$ solution is unique.

Comment: Right. I think the confusion might be due to me phrasing my original question as a general query about Fredholm integral equations. My general question is,

Comment: ... "Assume that, conditional on $K$ (i.e. conditional on $\beta$), there exists a unique $g$. When can we know that $g$ is a pdf?" Addressing the general question will help me prove the  conjecture: "Assume that there exists a $\beta$ and a pdf $g$ that solves the equation. There exists a $\beta' \neq \beta$ and a pdf $g' \neq g$ that also solves the equation."

Comment: This is all in the post now, so I think the comments can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up :)